# flutter: I want to Save user data from firestore to Variables but it returns null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hie, I'm new to flutter: I saved user data in firestore and im using the uid as the document name,
im trying to fetch data from firestore then save it into the variables.
[image: this is the layout of the database]

here is the code to which i'm trying to fetch the data into the variables:

```
   var  uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    var _phone = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).collection('phone').get().toString();
    var    _address = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).collection('address').get().toString();
    var   _admin= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).collection('admin').get().toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[phone, address,admin] are not collections. These are just fields.

```
final documentSnapshot = await collection('Users').doc(uid).get();
final data = documentSnapshot.data();

final phone = data['phone'];
```

Comment: ok, thank you.  so how do i assign the fields to variables

Comment: [data] is just a Map<String, dynamic>. So you can access values with key names. I made some changes my answer. Check it out.